# SQL subset of results in single result

Tags: sql, subquery

I've been using ORM tools for most of the time I develop. I need to execute some SQL - not inside my typical Rails environment.

```
  "SELECT projects.id, projects.company_id, projects.name, 
  companies.name as company_name,
  people.name as person_name,
  users.name as user_name
  FROM projects
  INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = projects.company_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN project_people ON project_people.project_id = projects.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON people.id = project_people.person_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN project_users ON project_users.project_id = projects.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = project_users.user_id"
```

If I select a single record I typically get multiple rows in the result e.g. if I have 2 project_people, and 2 project_users.

**I will get:**

```
  {"id"=>"7744", "company_id"=>"42598", "name"=>"Project with a name", "company_name"=>"(Confidential)", "person_name"=>"A person name", "user_name"=>nil} 
  {"id"=>"7744", "company_id"=>"42598", "name"=>"Project with a name", "company_name"=>"(Confidential)", "person_name"=>"Another name", "user_name"=>nil}
  {"id"=>"7744", "company_id"=>"42598", "name"=>"Project with a name", "company_name"=>"(Confidential)", "person_name"=>"Another name", "user_name"=>'Some user'}
  {"id"=>"7744", "company_id"=>"42598", "name"=>"Project with a name", "company_name"=>"(Confidential)", "person_name"=>"A person name", "user_name"=>'Some user'}
```

What I would like to have is the **following:**

```
  {"id"=>"7744", "company_id"=>"42598", "name"=>"Project with a name", "company_name"=>"(Confidential)", "people"=>{
              "person_name"=>"A person name",
              "person_name"=>"Another name",
        }, "users"=>{
              "user_name"=>nil, 
              "user_name"=>'Some user'
        }
  }
```

I know for some of you guru's in SQL you can easily solve this but I dread to think how terrible this is for me to ask such a lame question.  I'm sure that this is possible - with a single query

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this array_agg in postgres - seems to do what I need!

```
 "SELECT projects.id, projects.company_id, projects.name, 
  companies.name AS company_name,
  array_agg(people.name) AS people,
  array_agg(users.name) AS users
  FROM projects
  INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = projects.company_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN project_people ON project_people.project_id = projects.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON people.id = project_people.person_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN project_users ON project_users.project_id = projects.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = project_users.user_id
  GROUP BY projects.id"
```

I also found this removed duplicates ;-) - I dont how how this performs but it does the job well

```
  array_agg(DISTINCT CONCAT(people.id, ' ', people.name)) AS people
  array_agg(DISTINCT CONCAT(users.id, ' ', users.name)) AS users
```